# Collections of protocol instances

Tags: swift, generics, collections

Trying to [solve a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28503875/16892) that's irrelevant for the moment, I tried to do something in Swift that's pretty normal in C# code: define a couple of protocols to describe a producer-consumer relationship, and then to provide a concrete implementation of the producer:

```
protocol Consumer
{
  func someInterestingThing( producer: Producer )

  func anotherInterestingThing( producer: Producer, happenedBefore: Bool )
}

protocol Producer
{
  func addConsumer( consumer: Consumer )

  func removeConsumer( consumer: Consumer )
}


class ConcreteProducer : Producer
{
  private var _consumers = Set<Consumer>()

  func addConsumer( consumer: Consumer ) {
    _consumers.insert(consumer);
  }

  func removeConsumer( consumer: Consumer ) {
    _consumers.remove(consumer);
  }
}
```

This doesn't work, because my `Consumer` protocol isn't `Hashable`, which it must be to go into a Swift `Set`. (In C#, this doesn't come up, because *all* objects inherit hashable-nature.)

OK, so I'll define my protocol as inheriting from Hashable; not exactly elegant, but should work. Nope! Now all of the places I use it, I get:

```
error: protocol 'Consumer' can only be used as a generic constraint
because it has Self or associated type requirements
```

Apparently, this is because `Hashable` inherits `Equatable`, which defines `==` on itself. Literally in terms of `Self`, which places some [extra restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24926310/16892) on how the type can be used.

Maybe there's some generics magic that I don't grok yet that would allow me to declare the collection and the methods with types the compiler would be happy with?

I might try to do something smelly like define the storage in more abstract terms, and enforce protocol conformance on the add and remove methods. But `AnyObject` doesn't implement `Hashable`. (Is there some better alternative?)

I could try to box the consumers in a private wrapper that implements `Hashable`, but I'd need to be able to compare those wrappers, which would depend on the identity of the consumer, and then it seems like I'm back in the same boat.

All I want is to keep a bunch of these things in a collection, without knowing any more about them than absolutely necessary. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
protocol Consumer: class {
    func someInterestingThing( producer: Producer )
    func anotherInterestingThing( producer: Producer, happenedBefore: Bool )
}

protocol Producer {
    func addConsumer( consumer: Consumer )
    func removeConsumer( consumer: Consumer )
}

class ConcreteProducer : Producer {
    private var _consumers = [ObjectIdentifier:Consumer]()

    func addConsumer( consumer: Consumer ) {
        _consumers[ObjectIdentifier(consumer)] = consumer
    }

    func removeConsumer( consumer: Consumer ) {
        _consumers[ObjectIdentifier(consumer)] = nil
    }
}
```

- declare `Consumer` as `class` only protocol
- use `Dictionary<ObjectIdentifier, Consumer>` instead of `Set<Consumer>`

Comment: Ooh, I missed the bit in the book that mentioned class-only protocols. That's a useful trick to have up the sleeve. In this specific case, I'd guess that it's pretty likely that the consumers would, in fact, be objects rather than structs. But it'd be awfully nice if there were a more general solution to this problem.