# Why is withUnsafePointer using a new pointer (or different pointers)?

Tags: swift

Consider the following:

```
class MyClass {
    private static let c = MyClass()

    func shared() -> MyClass {
        return MyClass.c
    }
}

var a = MyClass().shared()
var b = MyClass().shared()

let message = a === b ? "same instance" : "different instance"
print(message) // "same instance"

withUnsafePointer(to: &a) {
    print("a: \($0)") // 0x0000000119dfcc18
}
withUnsafePointer(to: &b) {
    print("a: \($0)") // 0x0000000110abcc20
}
```

I would have expected the pointers to be the same. Why are the pointers different?

Comment: Related: [Same object different address. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178886/same-object-different-address-why)

Comment: Related? [Swift's memory management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446162/swifts-memory-management).

Comment: Yup! duplicate! thanks guys!