# Is it possible to generate a unique hash from a Swift closure?

Tags: swift, swift3, closures, hashable

Lets say we have the following struct which wraps around a closure:

```
public struct Task: Hashable {

    pubic var closure: RateLimitedClosure

    public var hashValue: Int {
        // return unique hash
        return 1
    }

    public static func ==(lhs: Task, rhs: Task) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}
```

What I would like is for the `==` function to return true if the closures are exactly the same.

I can then use this struct as the key to a dictionary declared as such: 
`var dict = [Task, (Date, RateLimitedClosure)]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111984/how-do-you-test-functions-and-closures-for-equality – You *cannot* compare closures for equality.

Answer (score 0):

There is no language construct that can do this.

I wonder if this question is even well defined. After all, A closure is really just a function pointer and the variables that it captures, right? Its easy enough to hash a function pointer, but its not so easy to derive hashes for all the arbitrary variables that the closure closes over.