# Switch/case with function/operator type

Tags: swift, switch-statement, operators

I want to implement a switch statement with operators, like this:

```
let op: (Int, Int) = Random.choice([(+), (-), (*)])

switch op {
case (+): // Compiler error
    print("addition")
default: 
    break
}
```

But it gives the error:

> Expression pattern of type '_' cannot match values of type '(Int, Int) -> Int'

I've tried syntax variation:

```
case +: // Another compiler error
```

> Expected expression after unary operator

So, looks like the compiler doesn't even recognize the operator under `case`. Is it possible to make such switch statement work?

*P.S. I'm not interested in pseudo-solutions like using random numbers instead of operators or creating a wrapper class for them.*

Comment: Can you share your code defining "Random.choice?" I'm assuming that's a custom function.

Comment: Functions/closures cannot be compared for equality, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111984/how-do-you-test-functions-and-closures-for-equality, that applies to operators as well.

Comment: (and https://stackoverflow.com/q/45270371/2976878)

Comment: @MartinR I'd say so, yup

Comment: @JohnAyers, I suppose the name of this function is descriptive enough :)