# How do you get automatic Equable conformance for an enum with a closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, enums, equatable

I have an enum that has several cases with associated values and it conforms to Equatable.

I now need to add another case that uses a closure for its associated value and was wandering how I could make it conform to Equatable without having to write out the custom Equatable conformance.

For example say I had an enum like below

```swift
enum CoordinatorAction: Equatable {
    case closed
    case goToHome(isSignedIn: Bool)
    case addedItem(_ itemID: String)
    case removedItem(_ itemID: String)
}
```

How could I then add the `didSuccessfulyAddItem` enum with A closure whilst still having automatic conformance to equatable without getting a compile error?

```swift
enum CoordinatorAction: Equatable {
    case closed
    case goToHome(isSignedIn: Bool)
    case addedItem(_ itemID: String)
    case removedItem(_ itemID: String)
    case didSuccessfulyAddItem(_ callback: (Bool) -> Void)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can’t have automatic conformance with this. You would have to write your own == function.

Comment: You can create a custom property wrapper to ignore properties from `Equatable`/`Hashable` conformance without giving up on the auto-synthesised conformance as [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Iron-Ham/d0eb72822f0965a3688241a70ec08f8c) shows.

Comment: There is no way to compare if two closures are equal, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/45270371/1187415.

Comment: Thanks all. I didn't think there was a way and was just hoping I was missing something. Appreciate the answers.