# Comparing functions in swift

Tags: swift, function, reference, compare

I just discovered that there is no possible straightforeward way to compare two functions in swift, meaning this code does not compile:

```
func foo1() {}
func foo2() {}
assert(foo1 === foo1)
assert(foo1 !== foo2)
```

This strikes me, because I know functions use reference semantics and therefore it shouldn't be a problem to compare two references, as it is possible in C with function pointers.

Can anyone provide me an explanation of this restriction and does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the errors?

Comment: cannot check reference equality of functions; operands here have types '() -> ()' and '() -> ()'

Comment: Swift is not supporting function or closure equality as of now. Please check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111984/how-do-you-test-functions-and-closures-for-equality

Comment: Oh, great, thanks, I somehow didn't find those answers