# Swift: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '() -> ()' operands

Tags: swift

Got an error when try to compare two closures:

> Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '() -> ()' operands

How should I do this?

For example:

```
enum SomeEnum {
   case caseOne
   case caseTwo(closure: () -> Void)
}

let e1 = SomeEnum.caseTwo(closure: {
    print("something 1")
})
let e2 = SomeEnum.caseTwo(closure: {
    print("something 2")
})

switch (e1, e2) {
case let (.caseTwo(l), .caseTwo(r)):
    return l == r // Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two '() -> ()' operands
    break
default: 
    break
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to compare two closures?

Comment: @Samah It's an enum case `loading(completion: () -> Void)`

Comment: Please show the source for the enum and an example of how you're using it.

Comment: @Samah please see the updated content

Comment: You can't use equality on enums with associated values.  Consider rewriting your code so that you don't need to check equality at all.

Comment: You can add the 2nd parameter in *caseTwo* which describes the closure, for example *UUID* or *#line* + *#file* of a place where the closure was generated

Comment: @Samah yes, I was trying to use `Equatable` protocol and failed

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What is the main purpose of comparing `e1` and `e2`?  Do you just want to find out if they are the same case?

Comment: @Samah yes, that's right

Comment: [Closures aren't equatable.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694072/3141234)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do comparisons of enums that have associated values, you will need to individually compare cases so that you can ignore the values of those that have them.

```
enum SomeEnum {
    case caseOne
    case caseTwo(closure: () -> Void)
    case caseThree
}

let e1 = SomeEnum.caseTwo(closure: {
    print("something 1")
})
let e2 = SomeEnum.caseTwo(closure: {
    print("something 2")
})

switch (e1, e2) {
    case (.caseOne, .caseOne), (.caseThree, .caseThree):
        print("both something else")
    case (.caseTwo, .caseTwo):
        print("both caseTwo")
    default:
        print("not equal")
}
```

Comment: Note that you could also join `(.caseTwo, .caseTwo)` with the others.