# swift:Unbind listeners which are closures from array of listeners

Tags: ios, swift, binding

I am trying to develop a theme engine, which loads themes from a `json`. I have a `Thememanager` which is a `singleton` class and holds a `currentTheme` variable.
I then have a `baseViewController` which listens to any change in the `currentTheme` with the help of `Boxing` technique, and all the viewControllers need to be subclass of
`base` and need to `override` the `observer` method to apply their styles. In the `box` class I have an array of `listeners` so that multiple view controllers can observer theme change simultaneously, it works well and now
my problem is that whenever a view controller gets `deallocated`, I want to remove that listener also from the box class array of listeners, which I am unable to figure out, because of which listeners are getting piled up.

I tried to write an `unbind` method in the deint of the viewController and tried to pass the closure like the below but it didnt work

```
func unbind(listener: Listener?) {

    self.listeners = self.listeners.filter { $0 as AnyObject !== listener as AnyObject }

}
```

Thememanager

```
class Thememanager {

    // Hold a list of themes
    var themes = [Theme]()
    // Private Init
    private init() {

        fetchMenuItemsFromJSON()
        // You can provide a default theme here.
        //change(theme: defaultTheme)
    }

    // MARK: Shared Instance

    private static let _shared = Thememanager()

    // MARK: - Accessors
    class func shared() -> Thememanager {
        return _shared
    }

    var currentTheme: Box<Theme?> = Box(nil)

    func change(theme: Theme) {

        currentTheme.value = theme
    }

    private func fetchMenuItemsFromJSON() {

        // TRIAL
        let theme = Theme()
        themes.append(theme)
    }
}
```

BOX

```
class Box<T> {

    typealias Listener = (T) -> Void
    var listeners = [Listener?]()

    var value: T {

        didSet {
            for listener in listeners{
                listener?(value)
            }
        }
    }

    init(_ value: T) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func bind(listener: Listener?) {

        self.listeners.append(listener)
        for listener in listeners{
            listener?(value)
        }
    }

    func unbind(listener: Listener?) {

        self.listeners = self.listeners.filter { $0 as AnyObject !== listener as AnyObject }

    }

}
```

BaseViewController

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    private var themeManager = Thememanager.shared()
    typealias Listener = (Theme?) -> Void
    var currentListener: Listener?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        observeThemeChange()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Bind the theme variable so that changes are immediately effective
    func observeThemeChange() {
        currentListener = {[weak self] (theme) in
            guard let currtheme = theme else {
                return
            }
            self?.loadWith(theme: currtheme)
        }
        themeManager.currentTheme.bind(listener: currentListener)
    }

    // This method will be implemented by the Child classes
    func loadWith(theme: Theme) {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = theme.navigationBarTextColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes  = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : theme.navigationBarTextColor]
        // Need to be implemented by child classes
        print("theme changed")
    }


    deinit {

        themeManager.currentTheme.unbind(listener: currentListener)
    }
}
```

Theme

```
struct Theme {

    // Define all the theme properties you want to control.

    var navigationBarBgColor: UIColor = UIColor.darkGray
    var navigationBarTextColor: UIColor = UIColor.black
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use Notifications to convey the theme change. Add observer for a theme changed notification in your base class and whenever theme changes in the thememanager, just post that notification.

Comment: @PuneetSharma Initial I thought of going with notifications and then found this binding approach and felt better, except this problem. I am using this for viewModel binding also in some other modules rather than using KVO

Comment: The Box object is holding the Viewcontrollers(listeners) strongly in an array. The deinit is never going to get called. It is a case of cyclic dependency.

Comment: @PuneetSharma The box object holds the closures and I have added weak capturing the closure, I am able to see that deinit of viewcontrollers are getting called

Comment: @anoop4real did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SleepNot Its been a long time since I worked on this... I will check my archives and see

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the comparison of closure in `unbind` method as it snot available for closures and functions(). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111984/how-do-you-test-functions-and-closures-for-equality).  I guess you could maintain a hashmap where listeners be the value and a unique identifier be the key. It is going to be much faster to unbind it as well.

But, I feel Notifications way is much better as it gives you the same behaviour(Publisher-Subscriber) without you having to manage the listeners.

Comment: This will give error "'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types"

Comment: If Listener is not an object, how are you comparing it as anyobject in unbind method?

Comment: I guess you typecasted listener to anyobject because compiler must have complained as !== is not available for closures. Thats why I was assuming the listener to be either a pointer object. After looking at the code again, it surely is not a problem of cyclic dependency but the conparison issue of closures in unbind method

Comment: yeah correct, closure comparison issue, I am trying an approach of setting an identifer ....lets see

Comment: @anoop4real: I guess you could maintain a hashmap where listeners be the value and a unique identifier be the key. It is going to be much faster to unbind it as well. But again, I feel this code is error-prone and adds added responsibility of generating unique keys.