# Swift Operator Identity Check

Tags: swift, collections, operators, identity, swift-extensions

## Operator Identity Check

### Swift 4.1, Xcode 9.3

I know that the `===` operator is used in Swift to check the identity of an operand. I have a situation whereby I want to check the identity of my operand against that of an operator – **I need to check if my `operation` parameter *is* `+` or `-`.**

---

#### What I Want To Do

```swift
extension Collection where Element: Numeric {
    
    func total(by operation: (Element, Element) -> Element) -> Element {
        return (operation === + || operation === -) ? reduce(0, operation) : reduce(1, operation)
        
        // For '+', '-', you need to use reduce with the initial value of 0
        // For '*', '/', you need to use reduce with the initial value of 1
    }
    
}
```

**Point of clarification:** *I am wondering how to check the `operation`'s identity, but Swift only sees the operator as an operator rather than its underlying function.*

---

#### Ideal Usage

```swift
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let totalSum = arr.total(by: +) //10
let totalProduct = arr.total(by: *) //24
```

---

### Final Question

**How do I check the identity of an `operator` (refer to its underlying function)?**

---

Comment: You need to use parenthesis in order to treat an operator as a function, e.g `(+)`. You cannot check the identity of functions though, as the results may not be what you expect, for example the compiler might have put them through thunks or specialised them. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/24111984/2976878

Comment: Also in your case, you would get different results from passing `+` to `total(by:)` vs. passing `{ $0 + $1 }`, which would be very surprising.

Comment: @Hamish, how do you suggest I fix this?

Comment: You could hack it by checking if `operation(0, 1) == 0` and using 1 as the base if it is which would at least work for +,-,/,*.